# Cómo acceder a la carpeta de inicio desde batch

Tags: batch

Necesito hacer un archivo batch que acceda a la carpeta "C:\Users???\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" sin saber cuál es el usuario. ¿Alguna manera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*¿Alguna manera?* Si, usar [variables de entorno de windows](https://www.rapidee.com/en/environment-variables), que para eso están!
Como pone en esa página:

- `%APPDATA%`:  Ruta-> C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming

También hay muchas más, que suelen ser muy útiles, te recomiendo mirar la lista si necesitas cosas como esa. Adjunto la lista como imagen por si la página desaparece en un futuro.
[image: Variables de entorno de windows]
La página está sin actualizar desde hace un par de años, pero al menos las que he probado yo siguen siendo válidas en windows 10, para comprobarlo puedes abrir Ejecutar y poner %APPDATA% y verás que efectivamente te lleva a la carpeta Roaming de tu usuario:

Comment: muchas gracias! Acabo de empezar con batch y todavá tengo muchas dudas estúpidas

Comment: Nadie nació aprendido. Recuerda que la mejor manera de agradecer es marcar como respuesta aceptada (además de paso ayudarás a más personas que puedan tener la misma duda) y mucha suerte :)